# View deallocated on a background thread : how to debug?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Sometimes my app crashes because a view is deallocated on a background thread but the problem is I can't figure out where it comes from.

Here is the crash log :

```
2016-11-28 12:21:44.753913 iCompta[3993:326592] -[NSView _registerWithBackdropView] should not be called off of the main thread. Invocation was here:(
0   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f082779 -[NSView(NSInternal) _unregisterWithBackdropViewIfNeeded] + 404
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0995b6 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursivelyNoteBackdropViewChanged] + 54
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f099685 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursivelyNoteBackdropViewChanged] + 261
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f099685 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursivelyNoteBackdropViewChanged] + 261
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f099685 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursivelyNoteBackdropViewChanged] + 261
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f159fdd -[NSTableView _removeBackgroundView] + 194
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f159f05 -[NSTableView viewWillMoveToSuperview:] + 65
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f03b4cc -[NSView _setSuperview:] + 695
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f1fddab -[NSTableView _setSuperview:] + 263
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f041205 -[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 447
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f3be133 -[NSOutlineView removeFromSuperview] + 56
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f1627ec -[NSView removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay] + 38
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f8d333e -[NSView _finalize] + 1008
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f04ece3 -[NSView dealloc] + 350
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f04eaf2 -[NSClipView dealloc] + 165
15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa5e47e8d _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 781
16  Foundation                          0x00007fff92fb3b9b -[_NSXPCConnectionExportedObjectTable releaseExportedObject:] + 350
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c5d74d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c53fcc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c6bb0b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 205
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c5d4f1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1174
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c56247 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 671
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c55f58 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 114
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000100ccb8c2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000100ccb39d start_wqthread + 13
)
```

The name of the crashing thread is NSFileCoordinate so it seems related to file coordination but that doesn't help me much. Any idea to debug this ?

Comment: The view is a `NSOutlineView`, do you remove one or close a window containing one? Is it an outline view with bindings?

Comment: Overwrite removeFromSuperview of that outline view and check if [NSThread isMainThread] returns false. Probably and update triggered by bindings in another thread.

Comment: @Willeke Yes when it occurs it is always after closing the main document window

Comment: I don't think it's related to bindings as my outline views are using data sources

Comment: Do you use `NSXPCConnection`?

Comment: No I don't use it

Comment: @Cyril Were you able to figure it out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @jmoukel Yes, I posted my answer below. Hope this helps…

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to solve the problem after much debugging. In my case the view at the origin of the crash is part of the window of a document and the crash sometimes occurs when you close the document.

When you close the document and there is a modification, asynchronous saving is launched and I discovered that sometimes the document is finally released on a background queue which then leads to the window and the views inside it being also released on that background queue.

So my solution was to hold a strong reference to the root view of my window in the dealloc method of my document and dispatching a block on the main queue after 1 second to nullify that reference. This way I ensure all the views are deallocated on the main thread.